# How to translate multi-segments to Drinfeld polynomials?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, hecke-algebras

Let $\hat{H}_m=\hat{H}_m(q)$ be the Iwahori-Hecke algebra of $GL_m$, see [for example](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011074v3.pdf), Section 2. The simple $\hat{H}_m$-modules are parametrized by Zelevinsky's multi-segments, See Section 2.2 of [the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011074v3.pdf).

There is a quantum Schur-Weyl duality between quantum affine algebras and affine Hecke algebras, see [for example](http://www.northeastern.edu/iloseu/Yi14.pdf). So I think $U_q(\widehat{sl}_n)$-modules will correspond to $\hat{H}_m$-modules for some $n$.

The irreducible $U_q(\widehat{sl}_n)$-modules are parametrized by Drinfeld polynomials. Given a simple $U_q(\widehat{sl}_n)$-module $V$ with Drinfeld polynomial $\pi(u)=(\pi_1(u), \ldots, \pi_n(u))$. Let $V'$ be the correpsonding $\hat{H}_m$-module. What is the multi-segment of $V'$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in equation (5.2) in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13575) which follows from [the paper: Quantum affine algebras and affine Hecke algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9501003).